# Path based authentication in Subversion failing for repository, but not path

Tags: svn, authentication, svn-administraton

I am using path-based authentication with svnserve, but it is giving me permission errors if I specify a repository. However, if I just specify a path then it authenticates.

In my authz file, if I do this it works:

```
[/my/path]
my_username = r
```

If I do this, it does not work:

```
[svn:/my/path]
my_username = r
```

I'm fairly certain that "svn" is the actual name of my repository. If someone could let me know how I find out the name of a repository, that might help. The repository is under /usr/local/svn.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This probably means there's only one repository known to svnserve. Please give more details about your current configuration if you want a precise answer and not guesswork.

Answer (score 0):

When you did svnadmin create _________ what ever you gave in that blank is your repository name. For path-based authorization you define your repository by name. You then can specifiy a path within the repository.

I primarily use HTTP Auth, so I'm not sure if there are any differences with svnserv.

Using HTTP Auth once you've defined the SVNParentPath you can give access to areas of the repository for instance a branch of business logic libraries to another developer like so:

```
[bizlib:/branches/2.0.x]
 dev_login = r
```